# How to get duplicate Rows based on few column values?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm looking to get duplicate rows from my database table based on these columns: TaskID, StudentID, DateChanged

Please let me know how to query this one. Thanks

Comment: changed the question, review and let me know.. Btw 'ala' answered that question and marked as 'Answer' :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
      SELECT Taskid, Studentid, DateChangeid
      FROM Table1
      GROUP BY Taskid, studentid, datechangeid
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

And if you want to display all fields, then try this

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 t
JOIN (  SELECT Taskid, Studentid, DateChangeid
      FROM Table1
      GROUP BY Taskid, studentid, datechangeid
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) temp
  ON t.taskid = temp.taskid AND t.studentid= temp.studentid AND t.datechangeid= temp.datechangeid
```

Answer (score 0):

From your description I think this is what you need:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE TASKID = 'TaskID1'
AND StudentId = 'StudentID1'
AND DateChanged = 'DateChanged1'
```

Comment: Hi, I don't have input values to pass. It's kind off getting duplicate rows but only with 3 column values.

Comment: Ah ok. Your question didn't make that clear. @Ala's answer will get you what you need.